# inserting a jquery variable into css

Tags: jquery, mysql, css

I am setting up a function where clicking a button sets an image to a fullscreen background etc. It gets the image_name from mysql, I can alert the filename so I know it is returning the correct information.

If I hard code the image_name it works perfectly, but if I return it directly from the db via ajax call it doesn't. I am completely lost as to why? Can anyone suggest where I might be going wrong.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: { value: value, id: id },
            success: function(image_name){      
            $('.click').hide(); //This will hide the button specified in html
            $('body').css({"background-image":"url(../article_images/"+image_name+")",
            "background-repeat":"no-repeat",
            "background-position":"center center",
            "background-attachment":"fixed",
            "-webkit-background-size":"cover",
            "-moz-background-size":"cover",
            "-o-background-size":"cover",
            "background-size":"cover"});
            }
            });
```

Comment: What is value of the variable, are you sure  you get the filename? You can check this with the Developertools in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

The value in `url()` needs to be in quotes:

```
$('body').css({"background-image":'url("../article_images/'+image_name+'")',
```

Comment: Thanks Spencer, just finished working it out myself.

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix:

instead of using

```
echo "$image_name";
```

in the php and jquery

```
$('body').css({"background-image":"url(../article_images/"+image_name+")",
```

I had a lightbulb moment and tried:

```
echo "../article_images/$image_name";
```

in the php and jquery

```
$('body').css({"background-image":"url("+image_name+")",
```

Probably not the right or best way to do it but it works - Finally!